# Simulate the 'Enter' key pressed in silverlight UI through code?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, automated-tests, ui-automation

How to simulate the 'Enter' key pressed by the user in the Silverlight UI application screen through C# code in my automated testcase?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Keyboard.SendKeys("{ENTER}");` or [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707824(v=vs.95).aspx) type stuff?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a solution like `UI Automation Framework` then simply look up if the element has an `Invoke Pattern` among it's Automation patterns.
The invocation usually does the exact same thing as clicking enter on a button or any other element.

if you are looking for a solution to simulate the actual press of the Enter Key, then you need to use `Win32 API` and use `Keyboard.SendKeys("{ENTER}");`